# Should Angular Services Manipulate the DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angular-services

So as I understand it, it's poor practice to have a service manipulating the DOM. DOM manipulation should be reserved for directives. I'd like to create something similar to a modal where a service is called to generate a DOM element.

e.i.

```
function MyController($sope, myModal) {

   // Submit a form
   $scope.submit = function() {
      if (formIsValid) {
         // do stuff
      } else {
         myModal.show({
            templateUrl: 'sometemplate.html',
            controller: 'MyModalController'
         }).then(function() {
            // do stuff
         });
      }
   }

}
```

Trying to think of different ways to do this and it seems like the simplest way would be to have the service inject a DOM element into the page-

```
function MyModalService($http, $compile, $controller, $rootScope) {

   this.show = function (options) {
      var $scope = $rootScope.$new(true);
      $controller(options.controller, {
         $scope: $scope
      });

      $http.get(options).success(function(html) {
         var ele = $compile(html)($scope);

         // Bad practice? Alternatives?
         angular.element('body').append(ele);
      });
   }

}
```

This may seem like small potatoes but I like to stick to a pattern and I like reasons to break pattern or to revise the pattern. Is this common or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Service seems like the proper place to do this to me.

Comment: I would have went with directives

Comment: @RichardHamilton How?

Comment: would do in directive also since proper scope is available. Just have service return response to directive function. WHy are you returning html in first place and not just data for a template?

Comment: I'm not returning html. I can't understand what you're saying. Could you provide a code sample in an answer?

Comment: In this case the answer can go either way. This is a bit different from modals in that a context panel is usually related to a specific element, which would make a directive very possible.

Comment: I will rename "contextPanel" to something else. It's a panel that sits at the bottom of the page and can be toggled open and closed. The contents can change often which would make a templateUrl convenient

Comment: service code shows you are returning html from server and then using `$compile` on that html.

Comment: @charlietfl That's to get the template file. I don't have template caching setup yet.

Comment: then I am really confused...what dom manipulation are you talking about?

Comment: @charlietfl That is the dom manipulation i'm talking about. I want to take any template and put it in the modal. It's calling an html file from the http server just like you would at every other step in loading a view.

Comment: At first glance your service doesn't provide much more than the `ngInclude` directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds very similar to what angular-bootstrap does for their modal.

You can check out their implementation here:  https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js (See line 452)